# How to apply md5 function to field in django orm?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

How can I generate this sql query from model without using objects.raw() method? DB is MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM model_table WHERE MD5(field) = 'my value';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have two ways:

**First way: Extra**

[Extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method: `Entry.objects.extra(where=["MD5(field) = 'my value'"])`

Pros: fast coding.

Cons: not index friendly, full scan, poor performance.

**Second way: new field**

Adding new field on model, `field_md5` and set it on `save`.

```
import hashlib
myModel(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field_md5 = models.CharField(max_length=16, editable = false )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        self.field_md5 = hashlib.md5.new(self.field).digest()
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Pros: fast performance.

Cons: database changes required.

EDIT: In python3 use

```
...
super().save(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

instead of:

```
...
super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

Comment: Thanx. This is best we have for it. I choose first one, passing dict to 'where' kwarg. Fullscan is avoided by other where conditions which is indexing. Important thing is we cant use .get() model method to add more conditions to request. Final version is:
Entry.objects.filter(**conditions).extra(where={'MD5(field)': 'my value'})